# How to get the URL of a selected image when using UIImapgePickerController with Swift?

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, swift2

The following code crashes because 'imageURLString' is NIL which I kind of understand. But playing around with objectForKey did not bring me to Eden either. Could someone please give me a kick...?
Thnx!

```
PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageDataForAsset(item, options: nil){
    imageData,dataUTI,orientation,info in
    let imageURLString = info!["PHImageFileURLKey"] as! String
    let imageURL = NSURL(string: imageURLString)
    print("imageURL: \(imageURL)")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`info!["PHImageFileURLKey"]` is exact `NSURL`. If you force cast to `String`. It will crash here. See this below code for fix that.

```
PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageDataForAsset(item, options: nil){
    imageData,dataUTI,orientation,info in
    let imageURL = info!["PHImageFileURLKey"] as! NSURL
    //let imageURL = NSURL(string: imageURLString)
    print("imageURL: \(imageURL)")
}
```

or safe code:

```
PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageDataForAsset(item, options: nil){
    imageData,dataUTI,orientation,info in

    if let _ = info {
         // info will not nil here
         if let imageURL = info!["PHImageFileURLKey"] as NSURL {
             print("imageURL: \(imageURL)")
         }
    }
    //let imageURL = NSURL(string: imageURLString)
    //print("imageURL: \(imageURL)")
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanx guys! that was the kick I needed.

Comment: :-)
by the way: it should be `if let imageURL = info!["PHImageFileURLKey"] as! NSURL? {`, right?

Comment: Avoid using unwrap `!` if you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`PHImageFileURLKey` directly returns `NSURL` and that is what your issue. You are assuming it to be `String`.